# python appium web traffic

Tags: python, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

We are doing some QA tests for our application and are using appium to drive the tests for the Android device.
We have been able to extract 'logcat', but are looking to extract network traffic (like you can in selenium-wire with `driver.requests`).
Has anyone managed to do this in Python / Appium?